# Do bees think it's summer underground?

Tags: dont-starve

If beehives are built underground, will the bees make honey during winter?

I do plan to bring flowers as well.

I haven't tried yet, I don't want to spent the resources if it wont work

(No dlcs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sort of.**

According to [The Don't-Starve Wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Bee_Box#Honey_Production):

> Even though Caves have their own day and night cycle and are in a permanent summer, Bee Boxes built underground will not spawn Bees. This is true even if the Box is built in a place where natural light can be found. The same applies to the Ruins since it is considered a permanent night there. However, if the Boxes are far enough from the player, the simplified model of Honey production will take over and Honey will be produced at a rate of 1 per day, in both Caves and Ruins.

Comment: Theres a tip somewhere that says you can get the bees out of the boxes by trying to harvest it, and then they'l make honey for the day...